# Trigger function when someone has stopped typing for 1 second

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input field which generates auto suggestions when someone starts typing. The user does not need to blur or hit a submit button for the suggestions to appear.

When someone has stopped typing I would like to run a function for tracking which products were shown to the user, along with the string of text currently in input field.

I added an 'input' event listener but I cannot get my logic right.

I want to `doStuff()` if it has been at least 1 second since the previous input event. Trouble is that my script is firing when a user starts typing not after since it's based on 'change' event listener.

And I'm thinking there must be a more logical way than I'm doing now.

Also I'm worried that 'input' event is impacting the users browser since it's running on every keystroke, maybe there's a better way?

Reluctantly showing my code block below even though it does not make much sense and is one of my weaker scripting moments, more showing that I have been trying different things. Would prefer a solution that ignores the insane logic I have been using.

I want to `doStuff(e)` when a user has 'stopped entering text in input' which is not an exact definition. When is a user considered to have stopped typing? For now I'm saying 1 second.

Don't want to use change event since it misses a lot of events where the user does not blur.

Prefer pure JS.

```
  var input = document.querySelector('#search_input');
  var newinput;
  var lastinput;
  var diff;

        input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

          newinput = new Date();
          if(!lastinput) {
            lastinput = new Date()
          }
          diff = newinput - lastinput;
          if(diff > 500 && diff < 2000) {
            doStuff(e)
          }

          lastinput = newinput;

        }, false);
```

Comment: You can try `window.setTimeOut();` after the event key up. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: @user3502626 Please write a proper answer. Don't use the comments for this.

Comment: @user3502626 there is no keyup event in this situation

Comment: How can there be no keyup event in a situation where you describe a user "typing"?

Comment: There is event for key pressed and release. I gonna write a code for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `input` event listener together with [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) as follows:

```js
var timeoutID;

document.querySelector('#search_input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    alert("1 second has passed since any input was received.");
    // doStuff()
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<input id="search_input">
```

The `setTimeout()` function queues up the function you pass it in the first argument to be executed after the specified number of milliseconds have passed. The `clearTimeout()` function cancel a currently scheduled timeout based on the id returned by `setTimeout()`.

So the function I've shown above basically says that whenever an `input` event occurs, cancel any previously scheduled timeout and then create another. Thus the code in the inner function will only be run approximately 1 second after the user stops typing.

Comment: This is great! Tested it and it works great - thanks. More philosophically, is it considered bad practice to use 'input' event due to stressing users browser?

Comment: @DougFir - It's fine. It shouldn't stress the browser.

Comment: @DougFir you're doing less stress because you're doing less work with each event being fired until the delay is exceeded.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is super helpful

Answer (score 3):

The technique is sometimes called "debouncing". While plenty of libraries like Underscore or Lodash have this, it can be accomplished fairly easily in pure javascript. It wraps a function that will be called when the debounce time is exceeded. It involves using `setTimeout()` and clearing and resetting the timeout each time an event is fired on the input. If there is a delay in the events and the timeout is exceeded, the debounced function finally fires.

From [David Walsh's blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

And to use it:

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);

element.addEventListener('keyup', myEfficientFn);
```

In your case, you'll want to add events to `keyup`, `keydown`, `change`, `cut`, `copy`, `paste`, etc.

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', myEfficientFn);
element.addEventListener('keydown', myEfficientFn);
element.addEventListener('change', myEfficientFn);
// etc...
```